# Similar to jQuery's end() in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there something similar to [`jQuery's end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) function in LINQ?

So I could modify a result set from a previous select?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing similar in .NET. There is not even a guarantee that an `IEnumerable<>` is enumerable twice (or that the two results will be the same). Often each enumeration will redo the query (or whatever it's). So for example if you do:

** CODE THAT REALLY WORKS, BUT BADLY! (SEE BELOW) **

```
var persons = from p in ctx.Persons select p;

foreach (var person in persons) { }

foreach (var person in persons) { }
```

where `ctx.Persons` is a table in an SQL Server, each `foreach` will redo the query.

I think it would be possible to build something similar in .NET (a caching stacked enumerator), but you would have to rewrite all the LINQ methods (and this only for LINQ-to-Objects)

There is another problem, more semantical: LINQ is a language for *queries*, there is no `ForEach` method. The methods of jQuery are different. They "act" on the items returned by the query. So the only "correct" place for something like this in .NET would be to be able to have more than one result-set for the same query... Something like:

** CODE NOT WORKING, JUST AS AN EXAMPLE **

```
var res = (from p in myItems select p).StackfulEnumerable()
                                      .Count(p => p.SomeProperty == 1)
                                      .Pop() // like the End() of jquery
                                      .Count(p => p.SomeProperty == 2);
```

and `res` in some is now a `Tuple<int, int>` (in some way... technically it would be very very complex to make it return a `Tuple<int, int>` in a type safe way, because in C# you can't build type safe generic methods with variable number of arguments)

Now, clearly someone could do this:

** CODE THAT REALLY WORKS **

```
var enu = // my enumerable

var res = from p in new[] { enu }
          let res1 = p.Where(q => q.Prop == 1)
          let res2 = p.Where(q => q.Prop == 2)
          select Tuple.Create(res1.ToArray(), res2.ToArray());
```

and it would be ok, but remember that you are enumerating `enu` twice!

Clearly you could play it safe:

** CODE THAT REALLY WORKS **

```
var res = from p in new[] { enu.ToList() }
          let res1 = p.Where(q => q.Prop == 1)
          let res2 = p.Where(q => q.Prop == 2)
          select Tuple.Create(res1.ToArray(), res2.ToArray());
```

now at least you know you'll enumerating twice something that is safe to enumerate any number of times you want.

Note that you could write:

** CODE THAT REALLY WORKS **

```
          select Tuple.Create(res1, res2);
```

but then every time you would enumerate the two enumerables of the `Tuple` you would enumerate again the "source" (unless you used the `ToList()`, as in the second example)

Comment: The `.Count().Pop().Count()` example that you gave midway through your answer, is that valid? I don't have access to vs right now, but it looks like it shouldn't compile. I couldn't make out from the surrounding text if you were talking about a hypothetical syntax.

Comment: @AmithGeorge It's an example if you built something like jQuery. It was to show that it wouldn't be useful. I'll clarify it.

Comment: Thanks @xanatos for an excellent explanation and for your time to go through with examples. I think your description that jquery acts on elements is very elegant.

Comment: seems "let" does not work. It does not compile: var q = from i in  new []{1,2,3,4,5} let odd = q.Where(t=>t%2==1)